# Rosdep install not locating definitions [rostime] [catkin] [rospy]

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace.html

When I run rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro foxy -y, I get the following output:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rospy_tutorials: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rospy]
roscpp_tutorials: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rostime]
ros_tutorials: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [catkin]
turtlesim: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [rostime]
```

My understanding is that rosdep looks for package names and keys. If I apt search rostime, for example, I get librostime0d as output. I have tried modifying package.xml with the search results.

I have tried looking through rosdep's base.yaml as this question suggests: https://answers.ros.org/question/350193/how-do-you-find-rosdep-definition-location/
but my rosdep isn't located at ros/foxy/rosdep, it's located inside /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2 and that folder doesn't contain a base.yaml file.

When searching for the packages using dpkg -S I am able to find them.

Where can I modify rosdep's definitions if not ros/foxy/rosdep/base.yaml or how can I otherwise instruct rosdep to locate the definitions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380881/rosdep-install-not-locating-definitions-%5Brostime%5D-%5Bcatkin%5D-%5Brospy%5D/) by [Daggrosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/75510/daggrosh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2021-06-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-23**:
The question is somewhat confusing.

You tagged it `ros2` and `foxy`, mention the ROS 2 Foxy installation tutorial, but the `rosdep` output mentions ROS 1 packages exclusively. None of those packages are used with ROS 2 Foxy.

Did something go wrong setting up your workspace?

I would refrain from editing all sorts of files until you've cleared that up.

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2021-06-23**:
I assume they cloned the wrong branch of https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials. The command to clone the branch for Foxy (as written in the tutorial) is: `git clone https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.git -b foxy-devel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you both. I live in China and for some reason cannot git clone from terminal effectively, with or without a vpn. SO I went to the github page and downloaded the zip. But I didn't switch the branch to foxy and instead downloaded the noetic zip.

---

Originally posted by [Daggrosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/75510/daggrosh/) with karma: 28 on 2021-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-24**:
Please just post an answer if you've solved your own problem. Do not edit titles to include words like `solved` or `answered`.

**Comment by [Daggrosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/75510/daggrosh/) on 2021-06-24**:
Noted. Thank you.